# lynda course on ruby - rails 4 incompatible

Tags: ruby, parameters, strong-parameters

So I'm doing the lynda.com rails course.

Since the course was recorded for rails 3.1 and I'm now on Rails 4 and they are now enforcing strong_parameters . I added the subject_params definition to comply with that but now i get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when i try to get the params[:id] on my previously declared class show. bellow is the code. method show was working fine before.

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController


 def show
@subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new(:name => 'default')
  end

  def create
    # Instantiante a new object using form parameters
   @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
   # Save the object
     if @subject.save
    # If save suceeds, redirect to the list action
  redirect_to(:action => 'list')
else
  # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
  render('new')
  end
end

private
def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:id, :name, :position, :visible)
  end

end
```

Comment: Did you check the url, what does it pass ?,

create an object in the rails console, & check whether Subject.find(some_id) works ..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `:created_at` and `:updated_at` and remove `:id`
Like so:

```
(params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible, :created_at, :updated_at)
```